# Postgres database has no password - can't get into pgadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, rails-postgresql, pgadmin

I have a rails app using postgres.  When I made the app, I never created a password.  In my database.yml file, no password is listed.  My application works, but I am trying to connect to the db using pg_admin so I can see the tables.  When I try to connect, I am given the following:

```
Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host
"localhost" (::1)    and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 3000?
```

How can i fix this?  If it helps, here is the code from my database.yml file for development:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: supersmart_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Do you have the password?

Comment: There is no password.  That's the problem.

Comment: If you're the admin of postgres, you tell it what to do. Either you want a password and you set one, or you don't want a password and set rules in `pg_hba.conf` telling it not to ask for it.

Comment: Where is pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Following your latest edit: _Connection refused_ is not related to a lack of password. Also note the port 3000 which is non-standard, postgresql is by default on port 5432.

Comment: Yes, it's not related to password. Can you try connect to postgres via terminal?

Comment: How do you do that?  I'm pretty new to postgres and its confusing me a ton.

Comment: `sudo su postgres`, then try those command lines. And this BS is why I always get `pgadmin3` and just click on it.